# Two Stack Exchange Team email addresses?

Tags: discussion, support, email

There seem to be **two email addresses for the Stack Exchange Team.**

> team@stack*overflow*.com

and

> team@stack*exchange*.com

What's the deal?  Which one is valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of them are valid.  There are also email addresses for SuperUser, ServerFault.

All of the "new" sites that are generated through the [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) process all use the team@stackexchange.com email.